# Capture checkbox value in an adjacent cell

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox

I have a raw data file that a user have already filled in with the data. Column A has the row headers such as Company Name, Company Address, Partner Name, Is the partner supplies qualified (checkboxes Yes,  No and NA in cell C12 for this row header since the row header text is in merged cells (columns A12 and B12). Column B has the relevant data. I have managed to write a macro to fetch the data for all the row headers other than the row headers with checkboxes using a for loop.

I am stuck with capturing checkboxes' values (Yes/No/NA). The issue is, there are 2 to 3 checkboxes in one cell and the code that I found would capture the values of checkboxes (if it is checked then TRUE/else FALSE) if it is in one cell. Also if the checkbox is in cell J30, the value of the checkbox would display in cell K28 which makes it very difficult to capture the values of the checkboxes for row headers.

Below is the code that I found in one of the forums to capture checkboxes values with TRUE/FALSE as result. When a checkbox is selected the value is TRUE and not checked then FLASE.

```
Sub Link_Check_Boxes()

    Dim chk As CheckBox
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    
    Set Ws = ActiveSheet
    
    For Each chk In Ws.CheckBoxes
        With chk
            .LinkedCell = .TopLeftCell.Address
        End With
    Next chk

End Sub
```

[image: Capture CheckBoxes]

I would need your help in cracking this.

Answer (score 0):

a) Having a checkbox "YES" and another "NO" makes not much sense as only one of them should be checked at a time. Either remove the "NO"-Checkbox or make two radio buttons ("option button"). The idea of checkboxes is that they exists independent of any other checkbox while the idea of radio bottons is that only on of them can be selected at a time.

You should think about changing the other checkboxes to radio buttons to avoid the "Select only one"-hint. With that, Excel takes care about that only one option is selected. To make that work, you need to group the options into group boxes.

Probably you don't want the groups to be "visible". I don't know how to hide them using only Excel, but you can hide them with a small piece of code:

```
Sub HideGroups()
    Dim ctrl As GroupBox
    For Each ctrl In ActiveSheet.GroupBoxes
        ctrl.Visible = False
    Next ctrl
End Sub
```

b) Link the checkboxes or radio buttons to a cell.

I assume you use form controls:  Right click, "Format Control->Control->Cell Link"
(For ActiveX-Controls: "Properties->Linked Cell")

There is no need to link the control to the cell it is placed in. You can use cells from a hidden part of your sheet or a hidden sheet. Bonus points if you give names to the cells. This makes is very easy to check the selected values because in your code, you no longer need to find the checkbox, you just access the linked cell.

Comment: Hi FunThomas,
Actually this is a form that was created by some other person and we have some 6500+ such forms and we are planning to create a database by capturing all the row headers and their values (i.e., transposing row headers to column headers and row data to column data). This is a one time request. Please help.

Comment: And none of the Controls are linked to any cell? And no one thought in advance how to get the data from the Checkboxes? And of course all the controls have meaningfull names like `Checkbox1`, `Checkbox2` ... Wow.